# CSS3 Transition Fill Mode

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations

Is there any way / trick to have transition keeping its state just like animation-fill-mode?

```
<style>
    #firstdiv {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        animation: firstdivframe 2s;
        animation-play-state: paused;
        animation-fill-mode: forwards;
    }

    #firstdiv:hover {
        animation-play-state: running
    }

    @keyframes firstdivframe {
        from { background: red; }
        to { background: yellow; }
    }

    #seconddiv {
        width: 100px;
        height: 100px;
        background: red;
        transition: background 2s;
    }

    #seconddiv:hover {
        background: yellow;
    }
</style>

<div id="firstdiv"></div>
<br />
<div id="seconddiv"></div>
```

[jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pexutika/1/edit)

Based on above code, I want the seconddiv to behave just like firstdiv without using any javascript code. The firstdiv will keep its state when the mouse stops hovering or the animation ends, while the seconddiv will always go back to its original state.

Comment: Short answer: keyframes & animation will do your work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it is not possible to use transitions for this. CSS transitions will only transition between styles (hence the name). If you want to keep a state you have to added a class, for which you always need JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

I think that this is what your are looking for

```
#firstdiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    animation: firstdivframe 2s;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#firstdiv:hover {
    animation-play-state: running
}

@keyframes firstdivframe {
    from { background: red; }
    to { background: yellow; }
}



#seconddiv {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
     animation: seconddiv 2s;
    animation-play-state: paused;
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}

#seconddiv:hover {
    animation-play-state: running
}

@keyframes seconddiv {
    from { background: red; }
    to { background: yellow; }
}
```

ckeck if it works: [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/pexutika/6/edit)

Please tell me if this is what you are looking for and then i will provide you a more "best-technic" solution with an explanation in each line. (i cannot currently comment).

Comment: you completely removed the transition and the style is identical with firstdiv's style

Comment: what exactly do you want to do your css? You want kind of an other way of doing the "animation-fill-mode" for the seconddiv?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, of course! Think about setTimeout! You can use setTimeout with the same duration as you have in transition! And the call-back function of setTimeout should set the back the style that you want to keep it!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. While your enthusiasm is a positive, please do be careful with the use of all-uppercase letters and punctuation on this site. Although you yourself may have good intentions, such grammar may be interpreted as rude or condescending by others.